# Можно ли как-то повернуть изображение заданое в qss виджета?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qss, qcombobox, qrc

Вопрос выше. Повернуть надо прямо в `qss`.
В **`CSS`** это делается так: `transform: rotate(180deg)`.

Может быть кто-то знает об этом?

**main.py**:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QComboBox
import sys
import res_rc


class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.comboBox = QComboBox(self)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(10, 10, 180, 20)
        self.comboBox.setStyleSheet("QComboBox::down-arrow:on {"
                                    "   "  # вот тут
                                    "}"
                                    "QComboBox::down-arrow {"
                                    "    image: url(:/ex/open.png);"
                                    "}")
        self.comboBox.addItem("Элемент 1")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Example()
    ui.resize(200, 40)
    ui.show()
    exit(app.exec_())
```

Файл **res.qrc** (который потом нужно скомпилировать в **`.py`**)

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="/ex">
    <file>open.png</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

---

Картинка:

[image: Картинка используемая как иконку]

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам не нужно ничего поворачивать. Вам нужно второе изображение.

**res_q1420979.qrc**

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="/ex">
    <file>open.png</file>
    <file>stylesheet-branch-closed.png</file>
    <file>stylesheet-branch-open.png</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

---

```
pyrcc5 res_q1420979.qrc -o res_q1420979_rc.py
```

---

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QComboBox,\
    QWidget
import res_q1420979_rc


class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralwidget = QWidget()        
        
        self.comboBox = QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(10, 10, 180, 20)
        self.comboBox.addItems(["Элемент 1", "Элемент 2", "Элемент 3",])
        
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)


StyleSheet = '''
QComboBox {
    border: 2px solid gray;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 1px 18px 1px 3px;
    min-width: 6em;
}
QComboBox:editable {
    background: white;    
}
QComboBox:!editable, QComboBox::drop-down:editable {
     background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,
                                 stop: 0 #E1E1E1, stop: 0.4 #DDDDDD,
                                 stop: 0.5 #D8D8D8, stop: 1.0 #D3D3D3);
}
/* QComboBox получает состояние `on`, когда всплывающее окно открыто  */
QComboBox:!editable:on, QComboBox::drop-down:editable:on {
    background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,
                                stop: 0 #D3D3D3, stop: 0.4 #D8D8D8,
                                stop: 0.5 #DDDDDD, stop: 1.0 #E1E1E1);
}
QComboBox:on { /* сдвиньте текст, когда всплывающее окно откроется */
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-left: 4px;
}
QComboBox::drop-down {
    subcontrol-origin: padding;
    subcontrol-position: top right;
    width: 15px;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-left-color: darkgray;
    border-left-style: solid;          
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;      
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}

QComboBox::down-arrow {
    image: url(:/ex/stylesheet-branch-closed.png);            /* <<=====< */
}
QComboBox::down-arrow:on { 
    top: 1px;
    left: 1px;
    image: url(:/ex/stylesheet-branch-open.png);              /* <<=====< */
}

QComboBox QAbstractItemView {
    border: 2px solid darkgray;
    selection-background-color: lightgray;
}
QComboBox QListView {
    color: palette(shadow);
    border: none; /*5px solid red;
    selection-background-color: lightgray;*/
}

'''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)                                 # +++                                

    ui = Example()
    ui.resize(200, 40)
    ui.show()
    exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**stylesheet-branch-closed.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**stylesheet-branch-open.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я вас понял спасибо!

Comment: @Kickwall пожалуйста.